# How can I pass a property from the scope of a controller back to a directive that's using that controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a in-place edit directive. I want to be able to attach it to any sort of element and when the user hovers that element an edit button should be displayed an once the button is pressed, a text field should be displayed allowing the user to change the content of that field.

I'm having a bit of trouble with passing back the edited value. How can I somehow bind the value of the `originalText` property from the `saEditableController` scope to the `saEditable` field?

Here's my code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('saCommon.editable', []);

    app.controller('saEditableController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.text = angular.copy($scope.originalText);

            $scope.submit = function() {
                $scope.originalText = $scope.text;
                console.log('In submit: ' + $scope.originalText);
            };
        }
    ]);

    app.directive('saEditable', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$compile',
        function($rootScope, $timeout, $compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',

                scope: {
                    'saEditable': '='
                },

                link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                    var $formElement, $inputElement, scope;

                    var onBlur = function() {
                        $formElement.remove();
                        $element.show();
                    };

                    var onKeyPress = function(event) {
                        // Escape pressed
                        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                            onBlur();
                        }
                        // Enter pressed
                        else if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                            //onBlur();
                        }
                    };

                    var onEdit = function() {
                        $formElement = $('<form ng-submit="submit()"></form>').
                            insertAfter($element).
                            attr('ng-controller', 'saEditableController');

                        $inputElement = $('<input type="text" ng-model="text"></input>').
                            appendTo($formElement).
                            on('blur', onBlur).
                            on('keypress', onKeyPress).
                            width($element.width()).
                            focus();

                        scope = $scope.$new();
                        scope.originalText = $scope.saEditable;

                        $timeout(function() {
                            $compile($formElement)(scope);
                        });

                        $element.hide();
                        return false;                        
                    };

                    var $editIcon = $('<a class="sa-editable-icon" href></a>').
                        hide().
                        on('click', onEdit).
                        appendTo($element);

                    $element.
                        css('position', 'relative').
                        mouseenter(function() {
                            $editIcon.show();
                        }).
                        mouseleave(function() { 
                            $editIcon.hide();
                        });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);

})();
```

The directive is used like this:

```
<div sa-editable="collection.description">    
    {{ collection.description }} 
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show how the directive is used.

Comment: I just edited the question to include an usage example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are using `ng-controller` on the form, it will create a new child scope, so you have to establish a way to communication between parent and child scope.

**Approach 1:** Using `scope.$watch()` and a dot-notation of model in scope.

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9MgWucf9JRuFe2A7qhlz?p=preview

Instead of storing the `originalText` directly into scope, wrap it with an object like this:

```
scope = $scope.$new();
scope.formModel = {
  originalText: $scope.saEditable
};
```

then you will be able to watch for the changes:

```
scope.$watch('formModel.originalText', function (value) {
  $scope.saEditable = value;
});
```

**Approach 2:** Using `$emit` and `$on` i.e. communicate via events.

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4CrcUPy8fk9xrauKLPbx?p=preview

You could subscribe using `$on` for an `'valueUpdated'` event like this:

```
scope = $scope.$new();
scope.originalText = $scope.saEditable;

scope.$on('valueUpdated', function (e, value) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $scope.saEditable = value;
});
```

and then `$emit` the event from the form controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.originalText = $scope.text;
  console.log('In submit: ' + $scope.originalText);
  $scope.$emit('valueUpdated', $scope.originalText);
};
```

Comment: Cool! I kind of like the first approach more. Can you please explain why do I have to wrap that property in a different object? Thanks!

Comment: That is because a "Prototypal Inheritance" characteristic of scope. You can continue by reading [Understanding-Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).